# Implementing logic functions using only an OR gate with one input inverted

Tags: logic, operators, logical-operators

I've been looking at logic gates, boolean expressions and Karnaugh maps.

I ran into a question regarding **whether it was possible to implement all logic functions using only one logic gate**: *an OR gate where the B input is inverted*.

I've devised the truth table for this, as follows:

a  b  out
0  0   1
0  1   0
1  0   1
1  1   1

I've also created the Karnaugh map for it and the boolean expression.

I've also attempted to create a few logic functions using the gate.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what method is best for determining whether this specific gate (or any gate, for that matter) can implement all/any of the logic functions, either through the use of Karnaugh maps, truth tables or boolean expressions (or any other method that would help me solve this)?

Thanks!

Comment: It may be easier to find an answer for this question in the math.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic. Your question can be phrased as "Is the operator (A or not B) functionally complete?" Since there are 16 distinct truth tables with two variables, you could exhaustively construct a network for each one using only your new gate. But a short-cut would be to just show that you can implement NAND using just combinations of your new gate.